# How to make an iOS app that re-signs itself (preferably using python)

Tags: python, ios, iphone, testing, altstore

I think that anyone who reads this question knows what altstore is. (Who doesn't know: an application that receives the user’s password and email and re-signs third-party applications installed on the iPhone through his developer account, so the application is able to function longer than 7 days). The reason why I don't want to use altsore it is because it is not official app and it's not working for me. In general, I want to do something similar, but I don’t know Swift or Obj-c. Maybe there is some simple code that I can write in Python and compile this application on iOS?
Just app that re-sign, after I'll try to figure it out myself.

Also, about what I tried, I don’t know at all where to start, and how exactly it needs to be programmed, how can I sign a certificate via python if this requires xcode, and xcode is only for MacOS. So I haven't tried anything yet. I can only assume that the application will ask for an Apple ID and password, then connect to the network, then (maybe) go through the official Apple website, it will re-sign the certificate or will try to reinstall itself, so everything will be ready.